# SQL equivalent "$all" MongoDB operator on Repeated string

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, google-bigquery

Suppose the following Data structure:

- MongoDB: {id: ObjectId, colors: String[]}
- SQL: Column ID (Integer), Column COLORS (Repeated String)

Suppose the following MongoDB query:

```
collection.find({colors: {$all: ["blue", "orange", "yellow"]} })
```

What is the equivalent operator/notation for "$all" in SQL? Notice that different from the $in, $all looks for documents (rows) having that field matching ALL the values, not only "some" of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates in the repeated values, you can use:

```
select s.*
from sql s
where (select count(*)
       from unnest(s.colors) color
       where color in ('blue', 'orange', 'yellow')
      ) = 3;
```

The "3" is the size of the list.  If there are duplicates, then use `count(distinct color)` instead.

If you don't want to "remember" 3, you can use:

```
with color_list as (
      select color
      from unnest(array['blue', 'orange', 'yellow']) color
     )
select s.*
from sql s
where (select count(*)
       from unnest(s.colors) color join
            color_list cl
            using (color)
      ) = (select count(*) from color_list);
```

Or even:

```
select s.*
from sql s
where not exists (select 1
                  from unnest(array['blue', 'orange', 'yellow']) my_color left join
                       unnest(s.colors) color
                       on my_color = color
                  where color is null
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp function check_all(arr ANY TYPE, match ANY TYPE) as (
  array_length(array(
    select distinct m from unnest(match) m 
    join unnest(arr) m using(m)
  )) = array_length(array(
    select distinct m from unnest(match) m 
  ))
);
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where  check_all(colors, ['blue', 'orange', 'yellow'])
```

if to apply to below dummy sample data

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, ['blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'] colors union all
  select 2, ['blue', 'pink', 'yellow', 'green'] union all
  select 3, ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow', 'green'] 
)
```

the output is

[image]